# Select if multiple variables missing

Tags: spss

How would I find the id of a person in my table who has SYSMIS for all the variables A,B,C & D? A to D are sequential variables.

I can't do a `select if` because it doesn't accept the `to` in:

```
select if (A to D) = SYSMIS.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
select if nmiss(A to D)=4.
```

If the variables weren't sequential you could use

```
select if nmiss(A, B, C, D)=4.
```